# SQL find values where a term is present but not in parenthesis

Tags: php, mysql, sql, regex

Is there any way to search for a term that is in the value but not in parenthesis?

Example: let's say we search for Bob:

> Bob(Not Bob) - Correct
>
> Bob(Tim) - Correct
>
> Tim(Bob) - Ignore
>
> Bob(Bob) - Correct

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE name LIKE 'bob not in parenthesis'
```

Comment: what?, can you clarify what data is in your table?. Showing a sample data and the desired result would be far better

Comment: MySQL supports [regular expressions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html)

Comment: @Lamak Select * from people WHERE name LIKE 'bob not in parenthesis'. Bob(Bob) would be correct but Tim(Bob) would not.

Comment: @robotmayo We mean "amend your question"

Comment: I suspect a non-greedy regular expression will do the trick here, as @mistermartin says. Can you try that, OP?

Comment: @robotmayo maybe precise your examples? should I look for values that are not in parenthesis? your last exemple would be correct, but bob **is** in parenthesis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE column NOT LIKE '%(Bob)%' AND column LIKE '%Bob%'
```

If bob is in parenthesis, it will fail even though the second condition is true, and if it's not both condition will be true, hence returning the value

Answer (score 2):

untested:

```
SELECT INSTR('myteststring','Bob') and not(INSTR('myteststring','(Bob)'));
```

Answer (score -1):

You could probably use a mysql function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION CheckForTerm (items VARCHAR(255))
RETURNS bit(1)

BEGIN

 DECLARE sf_result BIT DEFAULT 0; 

 SELECT count(*) from table where items in @item

 SET sf_result = 1;

 RETURN sf_result ;

END
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with functions, but does this check whether a string is in brackets?

Comment: You would need to augment this with a query inside the function that splits the content, along the lines of a very fnSplit (all over the internet) that creates a list based on a CSV list and then do an IF EXIST.  The function, as above, will allow you to return a "true/false" based on the existence of items, though.